# Best approach to refactor this java snippet

Tags: java

I was told it is not a good style to call potentially costly methods for boolean expressions (`getSupercategories()`).

```
private final SuperCategoriesResolver<ProductModel> catResolver = new SuperCategoriesResolver<ProductModel>() {
    @Override
    public Set<CategoryModel> getSuperCategories(final CategoryModel item) {
        return item == null || item.getSupercategories() == null ? Collections.EMPTY_SET
                : new LinkedHashSet<CategoryModel>(
                        item.getSupercategories());
    }
};
```

As well that `getSupercategories()` is potentially dangerous since it's backed by a relation attribute which might not be coming from local data members (`item` is sent as a parameter to a public method in this class and after wards is sent to `getSuperCategories()` which is overriden in the same class when declaring `catResolver`).

**Is this a better approach to tackle the argument above?**

```
private final SuperCategoriesResolver<ProductModel> catResolver = new SuperCategoriesResolver<ProductModel>() {
    @Override
    public Set<CategoryModel> getSuperCategories(final ProductModel item) {
        if (item != null) {
            Set<CategoryModel> superCategories = (Set<CategoryModel>) item
                    .getSupercategories();

            if (superCategories != null)
                return superCategories;
        }

        return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
    }
};
```

Where I first verify that `item` is not `null`. if it is, then a return `empy_set` if not then I called the costly method and get the collection and just if it is not `null` return the collection with elements.

Thank u very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to get more efficient to call `getSupercategories()` once instead of twice if it does any computation.

Do you need to return a copy of this set? You do in the first example but not the second.

Comment: That´s what I tried on the second approach.. does this one seem to be a better approach or is there something that could be improved?

Comment: The second approach may be better but you need to determine whether you need to return a copy of the result or not.

Comment: I want to determine weather getSupercategories() does not return null, so I called once and then if not return the copy; instead of calling getSupercategories() check not null and then return call getSupercategories() again and return which is not a good approach since it is a costly method

Comment: @Eduardo, That is what I said, can you answer the question I have asked twice now?

Comment: No actually I dont really need to return a copy. But if I dont return a copy how do I check that getSupercategories(); will not return null without calling it twice?. First time to check it does not return null and second time to actually return the value I require.. thanks!

Comment: @Eduardo, In your second example, you are only calling getSupercategories() once. I suggest you have another look at it.

Comment: Yes I know that is the whole point. That was why I was told and the argument of improving my code by calling getSupercategories() just once, because it is a very expensive method. Now you mentioned if I need a copy of the set being returned by getSupercategories() my answer is No. Now, my question is if I dont want to return a copy of this set (superCategories) how can I do that without calling getSuperCategories twice?? which was the first approach..

Comment: Put the results on getSuperCategories() in a variable just like you do in the second example. Instead of calling it a second time, use the result in the variable, just like you do in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach is indeed faster because there is only one call to the getSupercategories method if item is not null. However, in your second approach, you no longer create a LinkedHashSet instance -- which means it will behave differently (though faster).

This sounds more like performance optimization as opposed to refactoring. Usually when you refactor something, there is a "factor" in there somwhere, that trims the code down by eliminating redundancies.

Answer (score 0):

Nulls are your problem.  Can you make a refactoring to push nulls away?

For example, you could refactor your code to make `item.getSuperCategories` never return null?  Or do you need to distinguish between the empty set and null?

Similarly, why are you passing null into this method?  If you can eliminate that scenario then the code just becomes a one liner.